# Can burn bootloader but not sketches... thoroughly mystified!

Tags: bootloader, arduino-micro

I have a custom board designed to be essentially identical to the Arduino Micro (Atmega32u4). I can burn the bootloader (Caterina) and it burns just fine, including the fade-then-slow LED signal that indicates a successful bootloader burn. However, it does not turn up under USB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Explain better what you mean with "it does not turn up under USB". Add the details of how you burn the bootloader. Do you compile it yourself? How are you sure that it is flashed correctly? There is too little information in your question.

Comment: The bootloader has been burned straight from the Arduino IDE using a USBasp and a Diamex AVR (effectively the same as the MkII programmer). It completes the burn, completes the verification successfully, and uploads the blink sketch. At first run, the first 12 (I think) blinks are slow-fade.
When I then connect the board with a USB cable, it is not listed as under /dev as a tty device and it does not turn up in the Arduino IDE, either.

Comment: Oh, and to add to the weirdness: the board powers just fine from USB. It's also not a power issue as I get the same result with a reliable powered hub.

Comment: "Custom board essentially the same as" what is the difference?

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell you?

Comment: @Paul It has some components directly on its I2C bus. It is no different from an Arduino Micro with two I2C devices wired up to it. The power consumption is at least theoretically ok.

Comment: dmesg does nothing.